# After one lesson?

Tags: word-usage, dates

How to say that i will learn something not at the next lesson but at the next lesson after the next lesson.

For example, every Saturday I have a lesson, tomorrow is 16 February, how to say that i'll learn the thing not tomorrow(16 February) but on 23 February ? Is there a specific word?

Answer (score 1):

Native American English speakers would say "I'll learn [topic] at the lesson after the next."

Alternatively, we might also say "I'll learn [topic] at next Saturday's lesson." as in common usage, when referring to days of the week, the soonest upcoming day in the future is "this Saturday" (sometimes "this coming Saturday" or "this upcoming Saturday") whereas the "next" Saturday is the one *after* "this Saturday".